# Getting error when using FindBy in selenium. Error message null point exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, findby

```
import com.sun.javafx.PlatformUtil;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class HotelBookingTest {
    WebDriver driver;
    @FindBy(xpath= "//*[@class='hotelApp ']")
    public static WebElement hotelLink;


    @Test
    public void shouldBeAbleToSearchForHotels() {
        setDriverPath();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.cleartrip.com/");
        boolean hotelLinkDisplayed = hotelLink.isDisplayed();

       hotelLink.click();
        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

Getting error on line "HotelLink.click" and that hotelLink element is defined using findBy annotation but getting "java.lang.NullPointerException" error

Comment: Have you tried to wait for page loading and verify this behavior with display of the page you see in the browser while selenium runs (it usually helps a lot)? Also, are you sure that you should look for a `link` inside `class` but for the `class` itself?

Comment: Kindly share html source of it.

Comment: Update the question with the error trace logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using @FindBy annotation
you have to initialize the element before using.

you can do that by creating parameterized constructor accepting WebDriver type as argument.

````
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);```

and call this constructor after opening the browser.
i.e after this line 
```driver = new ChromeDriver();```
````

Answer (score 3):

As you are using `@FindBy` annotations, you need to initialize all the web elements before using it.

Create a construct for `HotelBookingTest` class and initialize using `PageFactory` like below :

```
import com.sun.javafx.PlatformUtil;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class HotelBookingTest {
    WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(xpath= "//*[@class='hotelApp ']")
    public WebElement hotelLink;

    public HotelBookingTest(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldBeAbleToSearchForHotels() {
        setDriverPath();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        new HotelBookingTest(driver);
        driver.get("https://www.cleartrip.com/");
        boolean hotelLinkDisplayed = hotelLink.isDisplayed();

        hotelLink.click();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Import `PageFactory` from corresponding package and remove `static` before the `hotelLink.

I hope it helps...

Answer (score 2):

For `@FindBy` annotations you need to implemet it before searching of WebElement.

You can add method that do it for you in a simple way:

```
import com.sun.javafx.PlatformUtil;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class HotelBookingTest {
    WebDriver driver;
    @FindBy(xpath= "//*[@class='hotelApp ']")
    public static WebElement hotelLink;


    @Test
    public void shouldBeAbleToSearchForHotels() {
        setDriverPath();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        HotelBookingTest.setPageObject(driver);
        driver.get("https://www.cleartrip.com/");
        boolean hotelLinkDisplayed = hotelLink.isDisplayed();

       hotelLink.click();
        driver.quit();

    }

    public static void setPageObject (WebDriver wd) {
        PageFactory.initElements(wd, new HotelBookingTest ());
    }
}
```